# rendering js server side

Tags: javascript, python

I have a webapp that displays a lot of interactive JS data tables and graphs in a single page (about 50-60). The page rendering required takes a lot of time (Chrome WebTools show about 20-25 seconds in the "Rendering" State from ajax response to completion) since each interactive element is a standalone "widget".

Because the types and structure of the tables/graphs is mostly constant and only the data varies, I think it's very inefficient to have the client render them each time. It would be better to send the client a rendered page and only populate the data where needed.

I've read about [Headless Chrome and Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr) but they are NodeJS modules. I was wondering if there was a way to incorporate this server-side rendering of JS in a Python-based backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can render React components server-side with [python-react](https://github.com/markfinger/python-react) or with [python-react-v8](https://github.com/nitely/python-react-v8).

*Installation:*

```
pip install react
```

*Usage:*

```
from react.render import render_component

rendered = render_component(
    '/path/to/component.jsx',
    {
        'foo': 'bar',
        'woz': [1,2,3],
    }
)

print(rendered)
```

More about the [render server](https://github.com/markfinger/python-react#render-server).